# populating recyclerview from API response

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-volley, httpconnection

I want to connect my RecyclerView to my API response.. as too many depreciated code I had to make the two separately but I still can't figure out how to put them  together I am putting the code if anyone would like to see it or having a problem with RecyclerView.. what I really want is giving me info or a thread or even a tutorial or how to combine both with the latest method as most of the codes online have problems, depreciated not detailed enough to show you the exact way to learn from it

---

code to connect to the database using httpUrlConnect

---

```
     public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    new GetMethodDemo().execute("http://YourIPAddress/android/search.php");


}

public class GetMethodDemo extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    String server_response;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

        try {
            url = new URL(strings[0]);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

            if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                server_response = readStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                Log.v("CatalogClient", server_response);
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);

        Log.e("Response", "" + server_response);


    }
}

  // Converting InputStream to String

private String readStream(InputStream in) {
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String line = "";
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (reader != null) {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return response.toString();
}
```

---

code for RecyclerView

---

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    List<ModelClass> modelClassList = new ArrayList<>();
    modelClassList.add(new ModelClass(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background,"1","day use","cairo","ain shokhna","take a day use from cairo to ain sokhna asdoibasidoasbd asodasidou asidua sdiuas dgpasidu agspiudasdiuasidgasiodgasiudgasoidugasdoiuasgdoiusagdasoiudgsaiudgasiodgasidgasiudgasiudgasoiudgasoidgasoiudasgdoiausdgaouisgduiasg uisag aisoug asiug aosiugdasiudgsauio gasuio gsaiodgasiud gasiug aosi","11/4/2019","20/4/2019","1000EGP"));
    modelClassList.add(new ModelClass(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background,"2","day use","cairo","ain shokhna","take a day use from cairo to ain sokhna","11/4/2019","20/4/2019","1000EGP"));
    modelClassList.add(new ModelClass(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background,"3","day use","cairo","ain shokhna","take a day use from cairo to ain sokhna","11/4/2019","20/4/2019","1000EGP"));
    modelClassList.add(new ModelClass(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background,"4","day use","cairo","ain shokhna","take a day use from cairo to ain sokhna","11/4/2019","20/4/2019","1000EGP"));
    modelClassList.add(new ModelClass(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background,"5","day use","cairo","ain shokhna","take a day use from cairo to ain sokhna","11/4/2019","20/4/2019","1000EGP"));
    modelClassList.add(new ModelClass(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background,"6","day use","cairo","ain shokhna","take a day use from cairo to ain sokhna","11/4/2019","20/4/2019","1000EGP"));
    modelClassList.add(new ModelClass(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background,"7","day use","cairo","ain shokhna","take a day use from cairo to ain sokhna","11/4/2019","20/4/2019","1000EGP"));
    modelClassList.add(new ModelClass(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background,"8","day use","cairo","ain shokhna","take a day use from cairo to ain sokhna","11/4/2019","20/4/2019","1000EGP"));
    modelClassList.add(new ModelClass(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background,"9","day use","cairo","ain shokhna","take a day use from cairo to ain sokhna","11/4/2019","20/4/2019","1000EGP"));
    modelClassList.add(new ModelClass(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background,"10","day use","cairo","ain shokhna","take a day use from cairo to ain sokhna","11/4/2019","20/4/2019","1000EGP"));
    modelClassList.add(new ModelClass(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background,"11","day use","cairo","ain shokhna","take a day use from cairo to ain sokhna","11/4/2019","20/4/2019","1000EGP"));

    Adapter adapter = new Adapter(modelClassList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

---

code for adapter

---

```
   public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.Viewholder> {

private List<ModelClass> modelClassList;

public Adapter(List<ModelClass> modelClassList) {
    this.modelClassList = modelClassList;
}


@NonNull
@Override
public Viewholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_layout,viewGroup,false);
    return new Viewholder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Viewholder viewholder, int position) {
    int resource = modelClassList.get(position).getImageResource();
    String search_id = modelClassList.get(position).getSearch_id();
    String activity = modelClassList.get(position).getActivity();
    String origin = modelClassList.get(position).getOrigin();
    String destination = modelClassList.get(position).getDestination();
    String description = modelClassList.get(position).getDescription();
    String date_from = modelClassList.get(position).getDate_from();
    String date_to = modelClassList.get(position).getDate_to();
    String price = modelClassList.get(position).getPrice();


    viewholder.setData( resource, search_id,activity,origin,destination,description,date_from,date_to,price);


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return modelClassList.size();
}

public class Viewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    private ImageView imageView;
    private TextView search;
    private TextView mactivity;
    private TextView morigin;
    private TextView mdestination;
    private TextView mdescription;
    private TextView mdate_from;
    private TextView mdate_to;
    private TextView mprice;

    public Viewholder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        imageView =itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        search= itemView.findViewById(R.id.search_id);
        mactivity= itemView.findViewById(R.id.activity);
        morigin= itemView.findViewById(R.id.origin);
        mdestination= itemView.findViewById(R.id.destination);
        mdescription= itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);
        mdate_from= itemView.findViewById(R.id.date_from);
        mdate_to= itemView.findViewById(R.id.date_to);
        mprice =itemView.findViewById(R.id.price);



    }
    private void setData(int resource, String search_id,String activity,String origin,String destination,String description,String date_from,String date_to,String price){


     imageView.setImageResource(resource);
     search.setText(search_id);
     mactivity.setText(activity);
     morigin.setText(origin);
     mdestination.setText(destination);
     mdescription.setText(description);
     mdate_from.setText(date_from);
     mdate_to.setText(date_to);
     mprice.setText(price);


    }
}
}
```

---

volley code doesn't work

---

```
     public class redirectFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String URL_PRODUCTS = "http://ipAddress/android/search.php";

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private List<ModelClass> modelClassList;


public redirectFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_redirect, container, false);

    recyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity());
    layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    List<ModelClass> modelClassList = new ArrayList<>();

    loadModelClass();

    Adapter adapter = new Adapter(modelClassList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    return v ;
}

private void loadModelClass() {


StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL_PRODUCTS,
        new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    //converting the string to json array object
                    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);

                    //traversing through all the object
                    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                        //getting product object from json array
                        JSONObject product = array.getJSONObject(i);

                        //adding the product to product list
                        modelClassList.add(new ModelClass(
                                product.getInt("activity_img"),
                                product.getString("search_id"),
                                product.getString("activity"),
                                product.getString("description"),
                                product.getString("origin"),
                                product.getString("destination"),
                                product.getString("date_from"),
                                product.getString("date_to"),
                                product.getString("price")
                        ));
                    }

                    //creating adapter object and setting it to RecyclerView
                       Adapter adapter = new Adapter(modelClassList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        },
        new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });

//adding our stringrequest to queue
    Volley.newRequestQueue(this.getActivity()).add(stringRequest);
 }
 }
```

---

code for retrofit and still doesnt work

---

```
private Adapter adapter;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    /*Create handle for the RetrofitInstance interface*/
    RetrofitInstance.GetEmployeeDataService service = RetrofitInstance.getRetrofitInstance().create(RetrofitInstance.GetEmployeeDataService.class);

    /*Call the method with parameter in the interface to get the employee data*/
    Call<SearchList> call = service.getSearchData(100);

    /*Log the URL called*/
    Log.wtf("URL Called", call.request().url() + "");

    call.enqueue(new Callback<SearchList>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<SearchList> call, Response<SearchList> response) {
            generateEmployeeList(response.body().getSearchArrayList());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<SearchList> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Something went wrong...Please try later!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

/*Method to generate List of employees using RecyclerView with custom adapter*/
private void generateEmployeeList(ArrayList<search> modelClassList) {
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

    adapter = new Adapter(modelClassList);

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}

I tried both codes and they work perfectly for the RecyclerView and for HTTPURLCONNECTION  .. I hope someone helps me with the issue of combining the two of them

I tried volley but results in the comeback as null so someone suggested that I have to work with HTTPURLCONNECTION and since then I don't know how to combine the two together. I will add the volley I used to work with

Comment: Hello Diaa, welcome to SO, for you question there are so many possible solutions like library you want to use for http connection (volley, Retrofit etc) architecture you wants to follow (MVP, MVVM) etc. You can go through this tutorial https://medium.com/@jacinth9/android-retrofit-2-0-tutorial-89de3c714c63 hope it will be helpful

Comment: So you want to populate recyclerview using the Volley?

Comment: yes,please im trying to .. ill try the retrofit tutorila @JaiprakashSoni suggested but i believe volley is much eaiser

Comment: @diaa retrofit is better than volley, it's your choice which lib you want to you but I will suggest you to use retrofit

Comment: @JaiprakashSoni you might be right i never used retrofit..im looking at the tutorial you posted right now ..trying to understand it then ill try to apply it .. thank you

Comment: @JaiprakashSoni i get E/URL Called: http://localhost/android/search.php?search_id=100
 and E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Comment: can you post your JSON response, please? @diaa

Comment: i get the on Failure response in MainActivity  --->public void onFailure(Call<SearchList> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Something went wrong...Please try later!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Answer (score 0):

Try this @diaa,

```
public class redirectFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String URL_PRODUCTS = 
"http://IPADDRESS/android/search.php";

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
List<ModelClass> modelClassList;

private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter; //new line

public redirectFragment() {
// Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// Inflate the layout for this fragment
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_redirect, container, false);

//getting the recyclerview from xml
recyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this.getContext()));

   //initializing the productlist
   List<ModelClass> modelClassList = new ArrayList<>();

  adapter = new Adapter(modelClassList); //new line
  recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);  //new line

  //this method will fetch and parse json
  //to display it in recyclerview
  loadModelClass();


  return v;
  }

    private void loadModelClass() {


  StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, 
   URL_PRODUCTS,
    new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                //converting the string to json array object
                JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);

                //traversing through all the object
                for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                    //getting product object from json array
                    JSONObject product = array.getJSONObject(i);


                    int search_id = product.getInt("search_id");
                    String activity = product.getString("activity");
                    String descp = product.getString("description");
                    String image = product.getString("activity_img");
                    String origin = product.getString("origin");
                    String destination =
                            product.getString("destination");
                    String date_from = product.getString("date_from");
                    String date_to = product.getString("date_to");
                    String price = product.getString("price");

                    ModelClass list = new ModelClass(search_id, 
                   activity, 
                        descp,image,
                            origin, destination, date_from, date_to, 
                      price);
                    modelClassList.add(list);

                }

                adapter = new Adapter(list); //new line
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);  //new line

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    },
    new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });
```

//adding our stringrequest to queue
   Volley.newRequestQueue(this.getActivity()).add(stringRequest);
   }

Comment: thats pretty good actually but still the problem was no layout error that i had before and someone suggested to you HTTPURLCONNECTION .. but i got an error response with JSON with only missing one string so i added if statement to check string before getting data and i got the error that its returning as a null .. im not sure but i read that some code for connection will be deprecated by the end of 2018 that why i needed an updated with async httpurlconnection as im using 28

Comment: but that really made understand something new .. thanks a lot

Comment: Can you explain me where you went wrong?And if solves then accept my answer please

Comment: after trying your code i get error for no adapter attached and i got JSON error for missing String(destination) so i had to check with if statement then i got error --> Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference

Comment: still the same error .. im really sorry ,i dont mean to waste your time

Comment: ill add another question just to show the missing parts maybe there is a problem in them .. but i really sorry for wasting your time

Comment: No not a problem.I have just changed the way of method hence its confusing

Comment: If you can send the code at where you got stuck i can help

Comment: i still cant send messages ill post the other question here

Comment: Sure @diaa.I will see

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55589366/populating-recyclerview-from-api-response-2